# A random trigonometry problem

Tags: trigonometry, problem-solving

I am a graduate student, I was solving some high school problems for a student of mine. I am stuck on this one for quite a long time. (Any high school problem solving technique is usable)

$\tan^2 (Z) \cos^2 (A/2+B/2) = \sin A \sin B$

How to prove that,

$$\tan^2 (Z/2) = \tan (A/2) \tan (B/2)$$

Comment: Please add some context. Where does this problem come from, what are your thoughts? Which methods are you familiar with for such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define Weierstrass variables $a=\tan\frac{A}{2}$ etc. so $\tan\frac{A+B}{2}=\frac{a+b}{1-ab}$ and $\sec^2\frac{A+B}{2}=\frac{(1+a^2)(1+b^2)}{(1-ab)^2}$. The given condition simplifies to $\frac{z^2}{(1-z^2)^2}=\frac{ab}{(1-ab)^2}$, whereas the desired result is $z^2=ab$. It therefore suffices to show $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$ is injective on $[0,\,1]$. [Here's the graph.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=plot%20x%2F(1-x%5E2))

Comment: Loved your answer, amazing.

Comment: J.G But why is it sufficient to show that the function is injective just in [0,1]? Range of tan is whole set real numbers.

Comment: @user398623 Unfortunately the function doesn't inject more generally. I was operating under the hopeful assumption you're working with acute angles, so the Weierstrass variables would be in that range. Otherwise, the result isn't true in general.

Comment: Which result? My problem?

Comment: Yes. If you choose from the graph two distinct $x$ giving $x/(1-x)^2$ the same value, say $_1,\,x_2$ with $x_1>0$, we get a counterexample from $a=b=2\arctan\sqrt{x_1},\,z=2\arctan\sqrt{x_2}$.

Comment: Okay. Really liked your technique, where did you learn about the Weierstrass variables? Are there any deeper uses of these variables? Or just for the sake of problem solving?

Comment: @user398623 They're widely used when integrating functions of trigonometric functions but, as you've seen here, they can also be used to simplify equations in trigonometric functions. There are actually two versions, one for circular trigonometric functions, one for hyperbolic. This allows a handy connection between the two via the Gudermannian function, of which one definition is $2\arctan\tanh\frac{x}{2}$.